# Customize notification received with parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I want to catch the notification sent from parse and then create the notification out of the json data sent out by the parse. I tried to change the default parse's GCM receiver with my own class using another SO answer but still only the default notification shows up.

My manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.mypackage.Notification"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

             <!-- IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name. -->
            <category android:name="com.mypackage" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

My custom receiver class:

```
public class Notification extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "MyCustomReceiver";
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    public static int numMessages = 0;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            String action = intent.getAction();
             String channel = intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Channel");
             JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));
             Log.i("mari ñapas", "got action " + action + " on channel " + channel + " with:");

             if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("my.application.technoat.NEW_NOTIF")) {
                 String title = "title";
                 if (json.has("header"))
                      title = json.getString("header");
                  generateNotification(context, title, json);
             }
           } catch (JSONException e) {
             Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
           }
    }

    private void generateNotification(Context context, String title, JSONObject json) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        numMessages = 0;
        NotificationManager mNotifM = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText("New Post in the Blog")
         .setNumber(++numMessages);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        mNotifM.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

        }

    }
```

I could still receive the notification but it is not generated by my custom class but by the default parse's notification handler. Could anybody point whats the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The codes were forked from many SO answers so I could link them all. Thanks to all the original authors.

this is my first SO answer. So if in anyway I could improve it, please do advice me.

So I made it to work by catching the notification, reading the json tags in stages and building the notification.

Broadcast receiver class:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final Dbhelper p = new Dbhelper(context);
        try {
            String action = intent.getAction();
             String channel = intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Channel");
             JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));
             Log.i("Got push", "got action " + action + " on channel " + channel + " with:");

             if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("My.app.package")) {
                 String title = "title";
                 String message = "";
                 if (json.has("header"))
                     title = json.getString("header");
                 if (json.has("msg"))
                     message = json.getString("msg");
                    numMessages++;
                    p.addCircular(title, message);
                  generateNotification(context, title, message, json);
             }
           } catch (JSONException e) {
             Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
           }
    }

    private void generateNotification(Context context, String title, String message, JSONObject json) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        numMessages = 0;
        NotificationManager mNotifM = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(message)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(message))
        .addAction(0, "Press to open", contentIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setDefaults(new NotificationCompat().DEFAULT_ALL);
        //.setNumber(++numMessages);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        mNotifM.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

        }

    }
```

Changed parse's GCM receiver in manifest to

```
 <receiver
            android:name="My.app.package.MyBroadcastReciverClass"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="com.sbu.sathyabama" />
                 <!-- IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name. -->
                <category android:name="My.app.package" />
            </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

And the json data to be sent is encoded as

```
{
     "header": "My notification Title",
     "msg": "My Notification message",
     "action": "my.app.package"
}
```

Comment: have u ever tried to send push notification to specific user by passing its object_id ....................

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the answers here are a bit stale. It used to not be possible to "intercept" the way Parse created notifications, so you had to create custom JSON blobs which didn't normally create a notification but instead broadcast an intent, listen to that intent, and then create your own notification. It was Android Judo and we worked hard to make a [better API](http://blog.parse.com/2014/09/30/android-push-gets-major-refresh/) with customizability in mind.

In short: Follow the updated tutorials, which will ask you to register the new com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver. To customize behavior, register your own subclass of ParsePushBroadcastReceiver instead and overload methods to your heart's content. If you want to get really creative with your notification rendering, just override [`getNotification`](http://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.html#getActivity(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent)).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Parse to send notification. Why you dont use the [ParsePush](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/Android)

Sample code to do a parse push:

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject("{\"alert\": \"The Mets scored!\",
                                   \"badge\": \"Increment\",
                                   \"sound\": \"cheering.caf\"}");

ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setChannel("Mets");
push.setData(data);
push.sendPushInBackground();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but this is not what I wanted as I receive push from parse and want to extract data from it and build a notification on my own. Answer is following this comment